# How to Open and Save Excel 4 files in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to import data exported in Excel 4 format from a legacy Access database.  Excel 2016 refuses to Save it.  In file settings, I don't see how to tell Excel to allow it.

Note: I cannot export the legacy Access database as CSV, as some of the notes fields contain CRLF pairs.

Comment: So you can import it into Excel 2016, but you need to (re)save it as Excel v4?  You say Excel 2016 "refuses to save it", what does that mean exactly? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I want to save it as an XSLX, but `Save` and `Save As` are grayed out.  I've just discovered a workaround. Excel will let me cut and paste the data into a new spreadsheet.

Comment: excel 4 was 1992 and `xls` - which should be fine in 2016. I imagine it's not excel, it's the files being protected or something similar like having incompatible objects.

Comment: I've also found a setting in File Block Settings: Open this type of file and allow editing... That does the trick too. I was thrown off by the fact that Excel 4 has a checkbox in the Open column but does not have a checkbox in the Save column, to enable Saving, as other formats do.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to save a legacy Excel 4 format in Excel 2016, Excel won't let you. But you can go in to the File Block Settings.  There you will see a three-column list, but there won't be a checkbox to enable Save for Excel 4.

```
Format    Open      Save
.
.
.
Excel 4    [ ]
```

Instead, look to the very bottom of the dialog where there will be three radio-buttons arranged vertically. Choose the one that enables opening and editing.